# Is creating an IBOutlet too expensive?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, iboutlet

A while ago I became a fan of creating/manipulating the view hierarchy through code. Both because I think is more expressive and forces me to learn more about Cocoa.

But I just wrote a 5 lines of code which would look way more expressive if an `IBOulet` was used. It finds a subview within a view with a specific tag and sends a message to it. But I could easily create an `IBOutlet` and do it in one line only.

Because of this, I ask: is creating an `IBOutlet` too expensive?

P.S.: Let's cut off the "readability over performance" for now. I really want to know the impact of this.

Comment: If you're creating your view hierarchy in code, how will you hook up the `IBOutlet`? An `IBOutlet` is only useful if you're using a XIB or storyboard.

Comment: If you just want a property that references a `UIView` that you create in code, you don't need to declare that the property is an `IBOutlet`.

Comment: @robmayoff When I said I became a fan of creating I was just stating a fact. It's not very important for the question. I'm using the storyboard and manipulating(this part is important) my view hierarchy. Sorry, It's a bit misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IBOutlet` is a marker for Xcode that gets removed by the time the preprocessing step is over. Internally, setting it up boils down to assigning a single pointer to an instance variable that "backs" the `IBOutlet` property. This pointer is assigned at the time the view is set up, and does not change after that. It is very cheap.

Finding a subview by tag, on the other hand, is a run-time operation that needs to run every time that you are looking for the subview. Usually it is cheap, but it may become considerably more expensive in a view with large number of subviews that have subviews as well.

Therefore, I would definitely go for `IBOutlet`, because it's a one-time deal, and because it lets you shorten the code from five lines to one.

Answer (score 3):

You have to be able to find out the pros and cons of your current approach. In fact Apple's documentation states:

> As with any item of object state, you should be able to justify its inclusion in a class; the more outlets an object has, the more memory it takes up. If there are other ways to obtain a reference to an object, such as finding it through its index position in a matrix, or through its inclusion as a function parameter, or through use of a tag (an assigned numeric identifier), you should do that instead.

I prefer to use `IBOutlets` in most cases, as (I know that you don't want to hear this) they make the code more readable and of course as @dasblinkenlight pointed out, your traversing of the view hierarchy is performed at runtime and therefore anytime (assuming you do this in viewDidLoad) the view is loaded.

My recommendation: Stick to `IBOutlets`, unless you have a really really simple view hierarchy and using tags to find your subviews is the best solution.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Apple recommendation here has to do with saving memory on the pointers (8 bytes per ivar on a 64-bit platform; plus 8 bytes of bookkeeping for the "weak" attribute). This is a classic time/space tradeoff where digging through the hierarchy at runtime takes less memory (you don't need a pointer ivar or "weak" bookkeeping), but costs more time. The worst tradeoff would be to avoid IBOutlet, but assign an ivar by hand.